# How to extract an id in json file using robotframework

Tags: robotframework

Json file:

```json
{
  "DWI_For_BugFix": {
    "Parent_DWI":"445894",
    "Traacks_Id":"385047, 375558, 375259, 336535, 347600, 291733, 291746, 415711, 433042, 433043, 44655"
  }
}
```

This is my robotframework test case

```
    ${jsonfile}=    Load JSON from file        Bug_fix.json
    ${value_1}=    Get value from JSON   ${jsonfile}    $.DWI_For_BugFix.Traacks_Id
    ${response3}=      input_text      xpath=//*[@id="jazz_ui_SearchBox_0"]/form/div/div/div/input ${value_1}  
    log   ${response3}
                 
    ${response4}=    click_element        xpath=//*[@id="jazz_ui_SearchBox_0"]/form/div/a[2]
    log   ${response4}
    ${src}=   RPA.Browser.Selenium.Get Source
```

I want to repeat the above test case for all Track_id
so How do i do in robotframework, please help me

Comment: When you say repeat the above test case, do you mean you want to run a loop inside the test case against each id or you want to generate a test case for each id?

Comment: ya exactly, please help me

Comment: Ok but which of the two options I asked for clarification on are you saying yes to?

Comment: I want to run a loop inside the test case against each id

Comment: "Traacks_Id" field in your json is *single* value. You can use `Split String` from builtin String and the examples even point out how this is done. See https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Split%20String